# Making the Facebook like news feed where user don't have to wait for new feeds using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have more than 1000 entries in database that includes images and text. I want to make my website load all that data base when it loads. But the problem is as I call my php function using jquery to load all the data my whole execution stops. I want that the function should be executing in background and be updating the DOM while user do different stuff

```
$(document).ready(async function ()
{
   await $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res)
            {
               DOM UPDATE
            }
       });
});
```

Comment: If you say "*whole execution stops*" then most likely the problem is this part here: `DOM UPDATE`. Given the details in the question, the only suggestion I have is "do it better". because I don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The problem is there are another functions present which also make ajax call but they won't get executed till this function finishes

Comment: I just want to know if there is any way I can make another ajax call and onclick functions work simultaneously with this